# Problem with handling exceptions, errors and return values

Tags: c#, .net, exception, error-handling, custom-error-handling

I need your advice. My source application become very.. expanded. And I have a little problem dealing with errors, exceptions etc..

For example I have "DatabaseProvider" class where are methods to contact with db. I have to deal with standard exceptions, invalid data form database (for example wrong email format), errors returned from database. All that stuff I need to return to the function which called DatabaseProvider's method, so that method will log this exception or error, and still working. So I can't throw exception.

And if that were not enough, I have to return (from DatabaseProvider) a value in most of cases or object or list of objects.

So I thought, maybe create a class "Response". And object of that class will be returned from every method in my app.

Sth like that:

> ```
> public class Response
> {
>     public bool Error { get; set; }
>     public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }        
>     public bool DatabaseError { get; set; }
>     public string DatabaseMessage { get; set; }
>
>     public Exception ex { get; set; }
> }
> ```

But how to return (for example) a list of self design objects in the same time?

Using "out" parameters are the solution? What is the best way (best practice)? I was searching about that, but all i found was how to deal with exceptions (only)..

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to implement a custom Exception? Is your aim to always return this information, rather than just when something goes wrong? From your example it looks very error-centric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would've recommended implementing a custom Exception which you can throw and catch, rather than returning this information, since it seems very error-specific.

However if you always want to attach certain meta information to returned results, you might implement a small vehicle class to wrap the results while carrying meta information:

```
abstract class ResultWrapper
{
    //meta info, such as error references/properties/flags/statistics

    public ResultWrapper([meta info])
    {
        //set meta info
    }
}

class ResultList<T> : ResultWrapper
{
    public readonly List<T> resultList;

    //constructor for resultList, plus meta information for parent
    public ResultList(List<T> resultList, [additional args for meta info]) : base([meta info])
    {
        this.resultList = resultList;
    }
}

class SingleResult<T> : ResultWrapper
{
    public readonly T result;

    //constructor similar to above
}
```

**Edit:** Based on your comments, you should definitely go with custom Exceptions which you can throw (possible wrapping cause Exceptions). As Petar said, these can be caught within the loop and processed there without halting execution of subsequent tasks. The language supports exception handling for good reasons - I would make use of it.

Also, fyi in your pattern:

```
public bool Error { get; set; }
public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
```

there is no need for the `bool`. Just check for non-null on the error message/reference field

Comment: Well, it is not that I'm not throw exceptions. I do, but there are situations, when an error occurs, you want to log that, but still return a value. 
And second reason is a problem with timer loop (I explained that in comment to Petar Ivanov's answer

Comment: Anyway, Is that good programming practice to return value with meta info? Is that popular? It looks very good, but if it is used very rarely and it's not good solution.. I have to think about it again

Answer (score 4):

I would implement a custom exception with all the data that you need to pass in case of exception. Something like

```
public class MySpecificException: Exception
{
    public bool Error { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }        
    public bool DatabaseError { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseMessage { get; set; }

    public Exception ex { get; set; }
}
```

You throw the exception and in the calling function(s) use a try catch block for your specific exception.

```
public void CallingFunction()
{
    try {
        //call your function
    }
    catch (MySpecificException ex) 
    {
        //log the data from the exception
    }
```

That's exactly what the custom exceptions are for.

This way you can still return from the function the thing that you want to return (a list or whatever).

Comment: I know, but I'm not sure yet. 
I've got a timer loop which gets a number of tasks, and execute them one by one. Now, When a random task will fail -> I throw an exception. The exception will abort the timer tick and rest of tasks in queue will not execute.
When a single task fails, I want to log that - but continue with the rest of them. I want to log everythink about what happened..

Comment: well, you catch the exception in the caller function - nothing will be aborted :)

Comment: So, The entire timer loop will be in try catch(Exception ex). Inside there will be another try catch(MyException myex) block, but inside this second it will be only "Execute" function. In catch(MyException myex) - I will log all the stuff in case of fail. I have to think about it once again, but it sound good.

Comment: there may not be a need for the outer try/catch, unless you foresee certain 'exceptional' exceptions slipping through.

Comment: you don't need two try block to catch two different exception - you can have two catch blocks for the same try: `try { } catch(Exception1 ex) { } catch(Exception2 ex) { }`.

Comment: I will go with exceptions. Thank you for help. I wish I could select both answers, but I have to choose the first one